# Doctrine oneToMany without mapped - YML

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I want to save user's ratings for a game.

For example: Battlefield 4 is a game, User is a user and user has 10 rating for this game.

How can i do this without using mapped attribute for oneToMany?

My yml (in user and game orm.yml files):

```
  oneToMany:
    ratings:
      targetEntity: CS\GamingBundle\Entity\Rating
      cascade: ["all"]
      fetch: EXTRA_LAZY
```

Comment: If I well understand what you want (you want to have an alternative to store the ratings without a oneToMany relation) you can store it directly in the user entity adding a `ratings` property (array on db).

Comment: I'm sorry i could not tell you clear. I want to keep ratings on a table: game_user_ratings with user_id, game_id and rating fields. I want to make a relation between these 3 entities (user, game, rating). I don't know how to do without using mappedBy with oneToMany.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't want to map the relationship because you're worried about loading in all the ratings when you load the user (hence the `fetch: EXTRA_LAZY`)? Using EXTRA_LAZY should mean there is no extra overhead so there's nothing to worry about.

You could just add the manyToOne relationship on the `Rating` entity without the reciprocating oneToMany relationship.

Otherwise you'll need to create a manager + repo and do everything manually. IMO it's not worth the trouble just use the ORM.